# How to add php files in drupal modules

Tags: drupal-6

I have a folder `/sites/main_folder/modules/file_folder/file.php`

I need to add file.php in the target.module file
`/sites/main_folder/modules/target_folder/target.module`. What is the perfect code for that?

I wrote this code in my callback function to add file.php in my target.module file but nothing happened:

```
$path=base_path().drupal_get_path("module","file_folder")."/"; 
require_once($path."file.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module. It helps you to keep all of your included library files in one location (namely /sites/**all**/libraries/). If you install and enable that module it gives you a libraries_get_path() function.

So you could then move your file_folder folder to /sites/all/libraries/file_folder/. Then to include the file you would do something like

```
include_once libraries_get_path('file_folder') . '/file.php';
```

Be sure to add libraries as a dependency in your .info file

```
dependencies[] = libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply use [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/6) as in the following example.

```
module_load_include('php', 'target', 'file');
```